# SSIS Package conversion from 2008 to 2005

Tags: ssis

Has anybody found a way to save an SSIS 2008 package in the older 2005
version?

We are running both 2005 and 2008 instances and packages designed under VS
2008 need to be deployed to the 2005 server. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

See [Sql server Integration Services 2008-2005 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924435/sql-server-integration-services-2008-2005-compatibility)

It has a reference to a useful ( even limited) tool

http://ssisdowngrade.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about saving your packages in a SQLServer store?  I recommend you use deploy to file system.  It is more flexible and there is no 2005/2008 restriction.

Comment: We use this method in our product.  No troubles unless you try to use something 2008-specific in your package.

Comment: when I try to load 2008 package into 2005 visual studio or through from integration services\file system\iportpackage\from file path
getting an error

Comment: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
"One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

Comment: See Microsoft KB articles 913817 or 300491 for possible causes & fixes.