# Execute SSIS package on sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssis

I've designed SSIS package, for sql server 2008 in Sql server buisiness inteligence studio. Now i need to execute in on SQL 2005 server. What is the best solution, withoute complitly rewriting package.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot develop for 2008 and then run on 2005.  That being said, try the answer to this question:

[SSIS 2008 2005 compatibility question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924435/sql-server-integration-services-2008-2005-compatibility)